# how to scale test data with respect of train data.?

Tags: r, scala, dataframe, svm

I notice in SVM function in R, test data is scaled with respect of train data. I mean it scales the test data with the mean and standard deviation of training data. Why this process changes dramatically the classification performance , I don't know!!!

I am wondering how it can be done? I know for train data I can use

```
   train <-  scale(train)
```

Comment: Scaling the Test Set? Why? Since the test data is standing for testing the performance of the model, it shouldn't be scaled as the train set. Because it has to be fair!  Have a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319514/why-feature-scaling-only-to-training-set) question.

Comment: @maydin please see this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65094/why-scaling-is-important-for-the-linear-svm-classification

Comment: I never used scaled test set, but it is interesting and apparently something I missed before. You may be right! Also, I found some other sources supporting your claim as well in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174823/how-to-apply-standardization-normalization-to-train-and-testset-if-prediction-i) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Should-scaling-be-done-on-both-training-data-and-test-data-for-machine-learning-Can-one-do-scaling-on-only-the-training-data)

Comment: In the post that you mentioned in first command also its saying the same thing.

Comment: I am just wondering if there is a shortcut in R or I have to do that manually!

Comment: I think this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13971/standardization-normalization-test-data-in-r) is what you want which is  using the `caret` library.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below code in RStudio:

```
df <- read.csv(file = "online_shoppers_reviews.csv")
split <- initial_split(df, prop = .7, strata = "Revenue")
train_data <- training(split)
test_data <- testing(split)

#Scaling Testing data with respect to Training data, i.e. you standardize the testing data based on the mean and standard deviation of the training data

train_scaled <- scale(train_data)

test_scaled <- scale(test_data, center=attr(train_scaled, "scaled:center"), scale=attr(train_scaled, "scaled:scale"))
```